# How to add a type constraint to a mapped type?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I am trying to add more typings to [MongoDB query system](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/#query-selectors).

I have an object

```
interface Person { name: string; age: number }
```

I want to create a query object that allows the operator [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) only on the `age` field because it is a number, not the `name` field.

`{ age: { $gt: 21 } }` would be valid, but not `{ name: { $gt: 21 } }`

Something like

```
type MongoConditions<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P] |
    { $gt: number }; // This condition should be allowed only if T[P] is a number
};
```

So this should be allowed

```
const condition: MongoConditions<Person> = {
    age: { $gt: 21 },
    name: 'foo'
}
```

But this should fail the compilation:

```
const condition3: MongoConditions<Person> = {
    age: 21,
    name: { $gt: 21 }
}
```

- [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gOwOZwMKICYEthcQZwB4AVAPigF4oBvAKCgagG0AFKLBKAawhDgDMoxALoB+AFxDWwqAB8aUACRJgkhAFcAtgCMIAJygBfANy0TtWh2D7+AQwDG0FvvyIFCW5oiT8wPRyRjKFskbygNHX0jC3sCYChYhGxcRABGSXhkNEwcPAQiZz1XBHIqOkZg0MkAJlSAGnpGDy9JAHJ+ODhWsxi4hJyUhGqMxBR0JNyCQkLi0ppGhhCw6iUVGtSjBormsPbO7sMLAHojoQALLHwofDO4dQAbDCg7LHuoYDPoWM0wV9tB2iJXz9CaDADMIyy42SeQKLkQc3KjCW6y2TU8y1WqigtWihwsQA)
- [Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to allow query operator only on "number" field:

```
type MongoConditions<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends number ? (T[P] | { $gt: number }) : T[P];
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gOwOZwMKICYEthcQZwB4AVAPigF4oBvAKCgagG0AFKLBKAawhDgDMoxALoB+AFxDWwqBAAewCAgz4oCAK4BbAEYQATlFFQAFMWlQAPjSgASJMEkad+qAF8AlFElmWwgNy0rgG0HIp6-ACGAMbQLPr4iNYIEZoQkvjAehxIflARSGlqWroGrrS0UQTAUJXKOHgIAIyS8MhomPUEhHF6CQjkVHSMeQWSAEyNADT0jMmpkgDk-HBwC4HltRk1HbiIYy2IKOh1uwhEPX0DNDMM+YXUtvbjjW7Tw3OFSytrZbQA9H8hAALLCqfBAuDqAA2GCgkSwUKgwCB0EqmjACIipwqVW2JwaAGYDm1jthTud4ogrkNGHdnm9Zil7o8HFAJm51kA)